# Is general linear group isomorphic to set of automorphisms on V?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm new to group representation theory. I saw two definition of group representation using $GL(n, R)$ and $GL(V)$ where R is commutative ring and V is n dimensional R-module. some books assert that two groups are isomorphic.
 I tried this by fixing basis but did not work; I defined map

$f:GL(V)\rightarrow GL(n, R)$ with $f(\phi)=M_\phi$ where $M_\phi$ denotes matrix representation of $\phi$ with respect to some fixed basis. I showed this map is bijective but failed to prove this is homomorphism because I got $f(\phi_1 \phi_2)=M_{\phi_2} M_{\phi_1}=f(\phi_2)f(\phi_1)$.

Comment: Think which matrix operations reverse the order of multiplication.

Comment: Do you define that a matrix acts on a vector on the right? This could cause the problem.

Comment: yes. I use $vA$ not $Av$ in usual

Comment: ah.. I see now. tranpose of matrix above is right in my notation

Comment: @fbg Or use the inverse.